# Why can i insert MaxDate but not MinDate

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sqldatetime

when inserting into my table with a nullable datetime column, inserting `DateTime.MinDate` raises the error:

> "The conversion of a char data type to
>   a datetime data type resulted in an
>   out-of-range datetime value."

Yet when i do `MaxDate` it works fine? 
I actually want to insert this value as null but in `PropertyInfo.SetValue()` passing null value is just automatically setting as `MinDate`, any suggestions?

Comment: What programming language and database system are you using?

Comment: i guess you are using reflection here as you do "PropertyInfo.SetValue()" but can you show us some more code, and what class are you in as you are referring to this in your comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sql Server `DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) has a range of 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31, while [.NET's `DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28VS.71%29.aspx) from 0001-01-01 12:00:00 midnight to 9999-12-31 11:59:59 P.M.

So `DateTime.MinValue` is lower then the Sql Server's minimal value, while `DateTime.MaxValue` fits into the Sql Servers `DateTime`.

---

Use nullables: `DateTime?` to be able to have a null in memory.

Comment: Nice and efficient then :S any way of inserting a plain old null to this value via c# when running an insert?

Comment: Just make the field nullable on db and don't pass any values if null.

Comment: If you are working with SqlCommands directly use DBNull.Value instead of null!

Comment: I have tried not setting it at all and also tried PropertyInfo.SetValue(this, DBNull.Value, null) and both are still sending in MinValue to the command text...

Comment: You can also use `SqlDateTime.MinValue`.